# Bootstrap button doesn't render properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have tried to use a bootstrap search box in my code that is supposed to be rendered like this:
[image]

But for some reason it does not render correctly in my layout which is something like this:
[image]

Here is my html code for this basic layout. Is there anything I can do so the button renders corrctly on the search box?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Weather Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="firstRow">
            <div class="col" id="top-bar">
                1 of 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="secondRow">
            <div class="col col-lg-3">
                <h4>Search for a city:</h4>
                <div class="input-group md-form form-sm form-2 pl-0">
                    <input class="form-control my-0 py-1 amber-border" type="text" placeholder="Search"
                        aria-label="Search">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text amber lighten-3" id="basic-text1">
                            <i class="fas fa-search text-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                2 of 3
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have to reorganize your html divs.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: the div with the class="input-group ..." should be inside a <div class='col col-12'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the below code. or below youtube link for the better explanation:

https://youtu.be/34Ee-HLtMgU

Only fontawesome library was missing.
I have added one more search box. try to add submit button instead of adding span tag. This is the best practice.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Weather Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="firstRow">
            <div class="col" id="top-bar">
                1 of 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="secondRow">
            <div class="col col-lg-3">
                <h4>Search for a city:</h4>
                <div class="input-group md-form form-sm form-2 pl-0">
                    <input class="form-control my-0 py-1 amber-border" type="text" placeholder="Search"
                        aria-label="Search">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text amber lighten-3" id="basic-text1">
                            <i class="fas fa-search text-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
              
              <div class="input-group mt-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">
                        <i class="fas fa-search text-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </button>
                    </div>
              </div>
              
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                2 of 3
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you missed this point, but you didn't include the "fontAwesome" CDN link. You need to use it to display the search icon. I also interpreted some of your code to create the image. You can check it.

And if you want search input to cover the entire line, you should use col-lg-12 instead of col-lg-3. The Bootstrap grid system uses a 12 column system. You must know that. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/

I used bootstrap's own classes to set border and icon background color. warning color for your situation

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dc0c634418.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <!-- <div class="row" id="firstRow">
            <div class="col" id="top-bar">
                1 of 2
            </div>
        </div> -->
  <div class="row" id="secondRow">
    <div class="col col-lg-12">
      <h4>Search for a city:</h4>
      <div class="input-group md-form form-sm form-2 pl-0">
        <input class="form-control border border-warning my-0 py-1 amber-border" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text amber lighten-3 bg-warning" id="basic-text1">
                            <i class="fas fa-search text-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="col">
                2 of 3
            </div> -->

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. First try changing fa fa-search in order to the icon display.

in this line => idk if u can use amber try using bg-warning (this is bootstrap), but if you want the exact color i would use css.
and maybe it is grey because the icon is not there.